# Fancybox - add class to the title depending on div id

Tags: jquery, css, class, jquery-plugins, fancybox-2

I have css classes such as .blue, .red etc that define background colors. I want to add specific class to div containing class 'fancybox-title', depending on the id that belongs to the fancybox

```
<div class="fancybox-skin">
    <div class="fancybox-title fancybox-title-inside-wrap">Welcome</div>  //here I want to add class, for example '.blue'...
    <div class="fancybox-outer">
        <div class="fancybox-inner">
            <div style="display: block;" id="login-register-fancybox"></div>  //depending on the ID from this line of code
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've had several attempts inside of:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    'beforeLoad': function(){

    }
});
```

including trying to find elements by ID, switches etc, but scripts started to look to big and to messy while not giving me desired result. I believe there is much simpler way to accomplish that, just can't figure it out. Can anyone help?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, accidentaly deleted the dot when pasting and cleaning the code for SO

Comment: Could you give some information about what you mean by "depending on the id that belongs to the fancybox"?

Comment: I have several 'boxes' (divs with various id's that contain different html elements, for example `<div id="register">`, `<div id="login">`), but fancybox automaticaly locates them inside of `<div class="fancybox-inner">` structure, while `.fancybox-title` is placed higher in the structure, as per example in my question. So I need to dig out that ID in order to define which class should be added to the title... and how to get that done is still a mystery

Comment: I understand you currently got something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/0x57y6q6/
Am I correct?

Comment: Exactly, now I need to add specific class (for example .blue) to helper 'fancybox-title' if that div's ID is 'register'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to provide you with two solutions:

First: The answer to your question "depending on the id that belongs to the fancybox" uses a switch statement and has the classes hardcoded. `this` contains an attribute `content`: the loaded content. By wrapping the content in a jQuery object we can get the id of the content.

Second: To make your code more generic I added a new attribute to your HTML `data-title-class`, this value of this attribute is set added to the classes of the fancybox title.

Both solutions use the callback `afterShow` because on earlier callbacks the `fancybox-title` is not added yet.

```js
$('.fancybox').fancybox({ afterShow: function()
{
    // First solution, based on id of content.
    var titleClass;
    switch($(this.content).attr('id'))
    {
        case 'register':
            titleClass = 'blue';
            break;
        case 'login':
            titleClass = 'red';
            break;
    }
    $('.fancybox-title span').addClass(titleClass);
    
    //Second solution, based on data attribute.    
    if($(this.content).attr('data-title-class'))
    {
        $('.fancybox-title span').addClass($(this.content).attr('data-title-class'));
    }
} });
```

```css
#register, #login { display: none; }
.blue { background-color: #00f !important; }
.red { background-color: #f00 !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

<div id="register">
    registering...
</div>
<div id="login" data-title-class="red"><!-- Second solution -->
    logging in...
</div>

<a href="#register" title="register now!" class="fancybox">register</a><br />
<a href="#login" title="login now!" class="fancybox">login</a>
```

Comment: Fantastic (and explanation too!), I went for the first scenario, removed `span` from this line `$('.fancybox-title span').addClass(titleClass);` so there's no need for 'span' element. Did exactly what I wanted, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can target instance of the `fancybox` being clicked using `$(this).fancybox('instance')` on your `event`. It'll give you an object with many properties. one of them is element, on which you can call `parentNode` for example, or anything you need. Like this will give you the id of the parent of the `a` element calling the `fancybox`:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    'beforeLoad': function(){
          $(this).fancybox('instance')[0].element[0].parentNode.id

    }
});
```